# Longest running string

Tags: java, strings, programming-challenge

I came across this problem in a career cup. Below I have the questions and the Java solution. I was wondering if anyone could scrutinize my code and tell me if there are any improvements, or better coding practices that I should know, as I am working on being able to produce proficient code.

Problem statement:

> Write a program to accept a nonempty string of alphanumeric characters. Define a `run` as a consecutive sequence of a single character. For example, `aaaa` is a run of length \$4\$. The program will print the longest run in the given string. If there is no single longest run, then you may print any of those runs whose length is at least as long as all other runs in the string.
>
> ```
> Example input: a 
>
> Example output: a 
>
> Example input: aab 
>
> Example output: aa 
>
> Example input: abbbbbcc 
>
> Example output: bbbbb 
>
> Example input: aabbccdd 
>
> Example output: aa
> ```

Solution:

```
public class StringRunCount {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(maxRun("aaabbbbbbbbcccccc"));
    }

    public static int maxRun(String testString) {
        int len = testString.length();
        String substr = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < len;) {
            char current = testString.charAt(i);
            String tempSubstr = "" + current;
            while ((i + 1) < len && (current == testString.charAt(i + 1))) {
                tempSubstr = tempSubstr + testString.charAt(++i);
            }

            if (tempSubstr.length() >= substr.length()) {
                substr = tempSubstr;

            }
            i += 1;
        }
        System.out.println(substr);
        return substr.length();
    }

}
```

Comment: Very inefficient. Never do `String = String + String` in a loop.

Comment: **1)** Construct `Strings` in loops using `StringBuffer` or something similar instead of string addition (which is very inefficient). **2)** if you know that `current == testString.charAt(...)`, why are you extracting the char again to concatenate to your `tempSubStr`? Use `current` instead: `tempSubStr += current;`

Answer (score 10):

You should keep 4 variables:

- The start index of the longest run
- The end index (or length) of the longest run
- The start index of the current run
- The iterating index

For performance, you'd likely also store the `char` of the current run in a variable.

When done iterating, return substring of longest run.

Answer (score 5):

Far too many `String`s. Why don't you store just a single character and count its repetitions, then copy the char and the number to some `maxchar` and `maxnum` if number > `maxnum`?

**EDIT** (code added):

```
public static int maxRun(String testString) {
    int len = testString.length();
    char maxchar = "!";
    int  maxlen = 0;
    char prevchar = "!";
    int  sublen = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        char curr = testString.charAt(i);
        if (curr == prevchar) {
            ++sublen;
        }
        else
        {
            if (sublen > maxlen) {
                maxchar = prevchar;
                maxlen = sublen;
            }
            prevchar = curr;
            sublen = 1;
        }
    }

    if (sublen > maxlen) {
        maxchar = prevchar;
        maxlen = sublen;
    }

    for (int i = maxlen; --i >= 0;)
        System.out.print(maxchar);
    System.out.println("");
    return maxlen;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It will be enough and cheaper to track the following variables:

- The length of the longest run seen so far
- The length of the current run
- The previous character
- The current character

Like this:

```
public static int longestRun(String testString) {
    int len = testString.length();
    if (len < 2) {
        return len;
    }

    int longest = 0;
    int currentRun = 1;

    char prev = testString.charAt(0);
    for (int i = 1; i < len; ++i) {
        char current = testString.charAt(i);
        if (current == prev) {
            ++currentRun;
        } else {
            if (currentRun > longest) {
                longest = currentRun;
            }
            currentRun = 1;
        }
        prev = current;
    }
    if (currentRun > longest) {
        longest = currentRun;
    }
    return longest;
}
```

This solution avoids unnecessary string concatenation, that is expensive.

Other notes:

- Instead of `i += 1` at the end of the body of the `for` loop, it's better to put `++i` in the `for` statement itself
- Since the purpose of your function is finding the "longest run", naming it `longestRun` would be more natural than `maxRun`

Answer (score 2):

You should honour the "separation of concerns" principle, e.g. not printing something to the console and then returning another value. I think it is better to return the String of the longest sequence (as finding out the length is easy).

I tried my best to use the new Stream API, but here it feels quite awkward (suggestions are welcome):

```
public static String maxRun(String testString) {
    return testString.chars()
            .mapToObj(i -> (char) i)
            .reduce(new LinkedList<String>(),
                    (l, c) -> {
                        l.add((l.isEmpty() || l.getLast().charAt(0) != c)
                                ? "" + c : l.removeLast() + c);
                        return l;
                    }, (p, q) -> { p.addAll(q); return p; })
            .stream()
            .max(Comparator.comparing(String::length))
            .orElse("");
}
```

Comment: BTW, I like how more intimidating such a train wreck becomes when you add an `orElse` at the end...

Comment: Ooh, I didn't know about `Comparator#comparing`

Answer (score 2):

Since we're dealing with a `String`, I suspect that we can use a regular expression to `String#split` it into chucks for further processing. Specifically, we want a regular expression which will partition every time a character is not like the preceding one. We can do this with [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
private static final Pattern SPLIT_REGEX = Pattern.compile("(?<=(.))(?!\\1)");
```

This pattern matches anywhere that:

- `(?<=(.))` given any preceding character we store in group 1 (positive lookbehind),
- `(?!\\1)` the following character does not match group 1 (negative lookahead).

So splitting the string `aaabbcdd` with this regex will produce the array `["aaa", "bb", "c", "dd"]`.

From there, we can stream and find the max element by string length:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class StringRunCount {

  private static final Pattern SPLIT_REGEX = Pattern.compile("(?<=(.))(?!\\1)");

  public static String maxRun(final String string) {
    if (null == string) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Argument cannot be null");
    }

    return Arrays.stream(SPLIT_REGEX.split(string))
        .max(Comparator.comparing(String::length))
        .get();
  }

  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    assert "a".equals(maxRun("a"));
    assert "aa".equals(maxRun("aab"));
    assert "bbbbb".equals(maxRun("abbbbbcc"));
    assert "aa".equals(maxRun("aabbccdd"));
  }

}
```

I learned about `Comparator.comparing(String::length)` from @Landei's answer, which I'm gracious for because I was expecting to be able to just pass in `String::length` by itself, originally. I also just call `get` on the `Optional<String>` returned by `max` because we've ruled out the only case the result could be `null` with our parameter check.

(Note that the last assert isn't necessarily valid, since any other two character substring would suffice.)